# Navigate to destination - If present on back stack restore - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a destination. The issue is I don't want to create a new back stack if that destination exists on the back stack

[image]

Eg. Navigate from D to B without creating a brand new B

How can I do that with jetpack compose navigation.

I am able to do this (From D)

```
navController.navigate(B) {
    launchSingleTop = true
    popUpTo(B) {
        inclusive = true
    }     
}
```

But this approach creates a new B

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the navigation from C to D like this using PopUpTo like you did:

```
//navigate from C to D:
navController.navigate(D) {
    launchSingleTop = true
    popUpTo(B) {
        inclusive = false //can be omitted since it's false by default
    }     
}


//from D, call navigateUp() or popBackStack() anytime to navigate to back to B
navController.navigateUp()
navController.popBackStack()
```